# How to write y i = β 0 + β 1 x i + β 2 x 2 i + e i in Latex code?

Tags: math-mode, r

I'm a beginner of using R and Latex. Just wonder how to write yi = β0 + β1xi + β2x2i + ei by using Latex?

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing…

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + e_i$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but the console board showed Error: unexpected '$' in "$"

Comment: @Louis The example I posted typesets without errors.  Maybe try https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+in+r